# Better method to map formgroup controls to optional function parameter with StrictNullChecks on

Tags: angular, angular-forms, tsconfig, strictnullchecks

So recently on my Angular project I turned on StrictNullChecks and have been going through and fixing errors. One error I found that I've been stumped by has been with FormControls/FormGroups.

I have 2 interfaces:

```
interface SearchCriteria {
    locationID: string,
    filters: {
        group?: SearchFilterCode
        name?: SearchFilterCode
        shift?: SearchFilterCode
    }
}

interface SearchFilterCode {
    codeID: number,
    codeText: string
}
```

These interfaces are used for a small filtering popup for a table.

I created a FormGroup to match the `filters` object:

```
filterGroup = new FormGroup({
    group: new FormControl<SearchFilterCode>(null)
    ...
});
```

The issue that I'm having is that after strictNullChecks was enabled, I had to add a null type to the formControl: `FormControl<SearchFilterCode | null>(null)` because of StrictNullChecks.

However, when I try to then map it to an object for an http request:

```
const obj: SearchCriteria = {
    locationID: 'abcdefg',
    filters: this.filterGroup.value
}
```

I get this error `Type 'SearchFilterCode | null' is not assignable to type 'SearchFilterCode | undefined'`. So I changed the formControl to `FormControl<SearchFilterCode | undefined>(undefined)` However, I instead got this error:

`Type 'SearchFilterCode | undefined | null' is not assignable to type 'SearchFilterCode | undefined'`

Is there a way to deal with the fact that FormControl adds a null type to each value and StrictNullChecks differentiates between `null` and `undefined`? I'm hoping I don't have to remap the `filtersGroup.value` object to a new object and just make all nulls undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [NonNullableFormBuilder](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#formbuilder-and-nonnullableformbuilder)

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks! This was super helpful! I legit wasn't able to find anything and I'm pretty sure it's because I was searching for the wrong thing.